# hashmap in java android, returning null values and repeating keys

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I am using the following code when getting data from firebase to convert it into a hashmap:

code calling method in fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("LOG", "onViewCreated: " + biViewModel.getBiFactorList(biViewModel.getBiSnapShotList(), biViewModel.getBiBehavior(), biViewModel.getBiInspection()));
    }
```

method itself in viewmodel:

```
 public Map<String, Integer> getBiFactorList(List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshotList, String behavior, String biInspection) {
        Map<String, Integer> factorMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : snapshotList) {
//check if snapshot matches user option and contains the field
            if (snapshot.getString("behavior").equals(behavior) && snapshot.contains(biInspection)) {

                String tempString = snapshot.getString(biInspection);
                Integer tempInt = factorMap.get(tempString);
//add k/v to hashmap
                factorMap.put(tempString.trim().toLowerCase(), (tempInt== null) ? 1 : tempInt + 1);

            }
        }
        return factorMap;
    }
```

result log:

`D/LOG: onViewCreated: {item,items,anentry=1, thougt,thought=1, thought=2, though=1}`

As you can see, thought=1, thought=2 should be 1 key with a value of 3, and several keys do not even have values

I have tried using different collections (somehow hashtable even returns null value), I don't understand why I am getting duplicate keys and null values when I should not be doing so when calling put

Comment: Note that `factorMap.get(tempString);` and `factorMap.put(tempString.trim().toLowerCase(), ...)` might potentially use different keys so `get()` might return null if `tempString` contains leading or trailing whitespace or uppercase characters.

Comment: Your output also indicates that your map contains the following keys: `item,items,anentry`, `thougt,thought`, `thought` and `though`. Those are all different strings so you might want to look into why you get those key values.

Comment: I see, unfortunately I only added that in after, I get the same result without it as well as .trim().toLowerCase() in both. I also don't understand why it is not trimming the whitespace

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but you should split `tempString` by `,` ?

Comment: Haha, actually you're right. Turns out I was getting data as a comma separated string, I just didn't realize due to the log message. Thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome, if you want to send message to one user include @username inside your message, otherwise the user will not receive it.